# string needs double quotationmarks VBA now confused to which quotationmarks are what

Tags: vba, append, quotation-marks

I need to append a string to a text file which has double quotation marks throughout it. How do I do that cause VBA is very confused at the moment

What the string should say/append the text file to (load "c:\test.lsp")?

Comment: Please don't scream. Also, starting your question with `LOL` might not be the best way to attract answers.

Comment: Yapp, caps and 'lol' for a start are a definite turn-off :)

Comment: VBA is very confused at the moment?  I'm very confused at the moment...

Comment: Ironically, the only thing not capitalised is the first pronoun "i", which should be!

Comment: Maybe his capslock is permanently stuck on.  See "vba" in the title.  :-D

Comment: lol, double quotation marks fail on caps lock users, lol

Comment: Looks like the downvotes were mostly for format (and, as such, deserved to some extent). The problem seems to have been resolved on edit, whether by the OP or otherwise, so I've upvoted to offset.

Answer (score 6):

You can double the quotation marks inside the string:

```
"""The Professional"" is a killer movie."
```

Or use `Chr(34)`:

```
Chr(34) & "The Professional" & Chr(34) & " is a killer movie."
```

Comment: THANKS FOR YOU INPUT MAGNUS HOFF (perhaps a hobby other then dogmatic would be nice) so the name playcat sounds like cat house

Comment: Ahhh "cat house" ... of course